# What does the argument to @Resolver for type-graphql do?

Tags: typescript, graphql, typegraphql

Honestly, just curious, on the documentation website for type-graphql, they pass an argument to the @Resolver decorator. Here is the link to the page where it occurs: https://typegraphql.com/docs/getting-started.html (under the "Resolvers" heading).

I've also included their code snippet here:

```
@Resolver(Recipe)
class RecipeResolver {
  constructor(private recipeService: RecipeService) {}

  @Query(returns => Recipe)
  async recipe(@Arg("id") id: string) {
    const recipe = await this.recipeService.findById(id);
    if (recipe === undefined) {
      throw new RecipeNotFoundError(id);
    }
    return recipe;
  }

  @Query(returns => [Recipe])
  recipes(@Args() { skip, take }: RecipesArgs) {
    return this.recipeService.findAll({ skip, take });
  }

  @Mutation(returns => Recipe)
  @Authorized()
  addRecipe(
    @Arg("newRecipeData") newRecipeData: NewRecipeInput,
    @Ctx("user") user: User,
  ): Promise<Recipe> {
    return this.recipeService.addNew({ data: newRecipeData, user });
  }

  @Mutation(returns => Boolean)
  @Authorized(Roles.Admin)
  async removeRecipe(@Arg("id") id: string) {
    try {
      await this.recipeService.removeById(id);
      return true;
    } catch {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

My code still works without the argument to @Resolver so I'm sure it's not that important but I'm wondering what it's used for?

Comment: @Liam please be friendly and helpful.
He just posed a question. When using a new technology or tool, you are always a beginner, and some things that seem clear to you may not be so to others.

Comment: When in doubt there's always reading the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's used in a [`@FieldResolver`](https://typegraphql.com/docs/resolvers.html#field-resolvers) method.

> Field resolvers in TypeGraphQL are very similar to queries and
> mutations. Create them as a method on the resolver class, but with a
> few modifications. First, declare which object type fields we are
> resolving by providing the type to the @Resolver decorator:
>
> ```
> @Resolver(of => Recipe)
> class RecipeResolver {
>  // queries and mutations
> }
> ```
>
> Then, create a class method (e.g., `averageRating`) that will become
> the field resolver. The method is marked with the `@FieldResolver()`
> decorator. Also, decorate the method parameters with the `@Root`
> decorator in order to inject the recipe object:
>
> ```
> @Resolver(of => Recipe)
> class RecipeResolver {
>   // queries and mutations
>
>   @FieldResolver()
>   averageRating(@Root() recipe: Recipe) {
>     const ratingsSum = recipe.ratings.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
>     return recipe.ratings.length ? ratingsSum / recipe.ratings.length : null;
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: I'm not sure there is a huge amount of benefit in just pasting the docs into an answer?

Comment: Cited via *italic*.

Comment: There is no FieldResolver in the getting started implementation so why do they pass the argument?

Comment: Best practice :)

Comment: This is the resolver of ? ... And you specify it in the decorator